# HLS vs HTTP format codes in youtube-dl

Tags: conversion, video-conversion, comparison, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl on windows 10 64 bit. I am new to this program. I checked the available formats for a video from dailymotion like this:

```
youtube-dl -F "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/". In the output, I see two kinds of format codes. Here are the best available options for both format codes:

hls-480-3    mp4        848x480     836k , avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2
http-720     mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

- What are HLS and HTTP?
- Which is the better format in terms of audio and video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by youtube-dl, the (best) format available is in mp4 with 720p resolution or 1280x720.

[HLS or HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) has lower resolution available for your current download link and is only available in 848x480 or 480p.